# Error in AndroidManifest.xml "must have a minimum of 2 segments"

Tags: android, error-handling, manifest

I tried change my package name like com.project_name but it didn't figure out. What is the real problem in my project?

I'm getting the following error:

> Error in AndroidManifest.XML file "Application package 'AndroidManifest.xml' must have a minimum of 2 segments"

AndroidManifest.XML file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rssreader"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.01" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="15"
        android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: it should be like com.something.project_name, how I do it: com.bigflow.project_name

Comment: com.project_name is acceptable. @Serkan how did you change your package name? By refactoring?

Comment: First, how did you even create a project with a single package segment?

Comment: please, show your Manifest.xml file and your main activity package name, it will be helpfull

Comment: @Asok yes ı changed by refactoring->rename

Comment: Alright, if you don't mind, please edit your question to include your Manifiest.xml as @Fess mentioned.

Comment: @Serkan Please, provide your main activity  package name

Comment: my main activity package name also com.rssreader

Comment: Try to recreate your R file by using `clear` + `refresh`. Go to Project-> Clean. After refresh your project.

Comment: ok thanks @Fess it figured out when restart my eclipse ide

Answer (score 0):

This may be a red herring. I've never got it because I've always used full corporate hierarchy (which has certainly been longer than two levels deep). You do not show (why would you know to show it?) the package name of your main *ListActivity* code. Let's say this is *RssReader.java*: This must be at *com.rssreader.RssReader.java*. That should do it. If you find your main activity isn't at that place, fix it. If it still doesn't work, then add an additional level of hierarchy to your package name and try that too, which surely should solve it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

At least when I started my project creation starting from this page
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

I got exactly same problem. That was solved by using the following command to create a project.

```
.\create c:\html\myapp **com.**my_package my_app
```

In the original instructions, `com.`  was missing.
This solved my problem