# Application package 'AndroidManifest.xml' must have a minimum of 2 segments

Tags: android, android-manifest

I read this:
     [Error in AndroidManifest.xml "must have a minimum of 2 segments"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417302/error-in-androidmanifest-xml-must-have-a-minimum-of-2-segments)  but there is no solution.

Its happen after I change the name of the project by refactor->rename (instead com.example.my app to myapp only) and after that I change the name also in the manifest.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="save_money"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="save_money.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="save_money.Article"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_article" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="save_money.HashmalActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_hashmal" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="save_money.ImageAdapter"
            android:label="a" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="save_money.SavedItems"
            android:label="פריטים שמורים" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="save_money.Screen2HashmalActivity"
            android:label="עלות צריכה" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="save_money.SelectArticle"
            android:label="בחר מאמר" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i think that the answer in the other question had it right: do not call your project "save_money" but "com.save_money" at least, even if i personally suggest you "com.yournickname_or_company.savemoney"

Comment: `com.example.my app` could not have been your original package name. Package names cannot have spaces in them. You really shouldn't use `save_money` as a package name. When picking a package name you should strive to make it unique as errors will arise if two apps have the same one. Further more your package name is not "user facing" so there is no need for you to use marketing jargon in it, basically no one will see it so there is no point.

Comment: google resstrinct the name: You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.  
"com" without "example" is ok?

Comment: Moreover, since you need a Web site in order to market your app, you need to go buy a domain name for that Web site. Use that domain name, rather than just making something up, particularly something that could potentially collide with somebody else's actual domain name.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What it means is the package declaration in your manifest must have at least two portions separated by a period (.). Instead of just saying `package="save_money"`, change it to `package="com.save_money"`. That should remove your error. Likewise, everywhere you specify the name of an activity, you also need to update it there. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you need to have a minimum of 2 segments for your package name.
So instead of `package="save_money` Try `package="me.save_money"` or whatever you want.